# How to enhance Text on this old photograph

Tags: photo-editing, filters

[image: St AQndrews Church, Dalhousie Sq, Calcutta (now Kolkata) 1880]

I was trying to ientify two buildings on the right side of the Church. However despite best of my effort I could not identified them. One building (white  one story building)  has a sign mark but I could not read them despite enhancing them using Fotor S/w.
Could any one please help me to read the sign on the building of this 1880 picture.

This is a drwaing from otherside (from church) available at British Library. 
Its Text are some what more readble.
http://www.bl.uk/onlinegallery/onlineex/apac/other/zoomify65490.html

Comment: Do you have a larger version? That one is down at about 4 pixels per letter, not really enough to reconstruct anything from.

Comment: a short google search of the image shows that this is St. Andrew's Church - Calcutta around 1878 and i think with this small picture it would be easier to make a google search around the building and if you find another image of the building and its name instead of trying to read the sign on this image. even though this solution would then be off scope to this site.

Comment: No additional picture is available. I could identify other buildings in another picture where rest of the street is shown. That is done by maching with contemporary directories. However for the small 1 story building no clear conclusion could be taken as different directories have given different name for the business. That is the reason I was trying to read the sign on the building.

Comment: @Tetsujin Here is the bigger picture. I could locate it at BL Site. But cant Read beyond "Wine &"    http://www.bl.uk/onlinegallery/onlineex/apac/photocoll/s/zoomify62498.html

Comment: Since there's not much room for more, I expect that says "&c", an old-fashioned way to write "etc.". But I'm also not sure this is really a _photography_ question per se — there's no "magic zoom and enhance" button, so there's really not much to be done with _this_ photograph....

Comment: Wait...there’s no “enhance” button?? You mean those crime shows are lying to me!?

Comment: "Missing Flash Plugin" .. erm, no, missing security fail. No-one should still be using Flash in this day & age.

Comment: vtc b/c While an interesting puzzle, reading illegible texts in low-resolution images is not generally relevant to photography.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the goal is not in the pursuit of creating a photograph. This may be a better fit for the graphic design stack.

Answer (score 3):

There are many scaling options (such as bicubic, bilinear, and nearest neighbor) which can be used in image processing. There isn't one algorithm that will always yield the best results, but [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) often does well.

The text above Wines seems to read "BAY AND CO"
[image: building]